# Replacing a single value in array stored in state with user input --Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, event-handling, state

I am creating a react madlibs app, and I want to update *this.state.blanks* array one item at a time when the user inputs words. I think I must be having trouble binding(but I thought having the fat arrow function bound it)? or I've just approached the problem the wrong way.

with my code the way it is now, I consistently get the error **"cannot read property 'value' of undefined"** (referring to the *e.target.value* in the *handleEnterWord* function)

here is what the problematic section of my code looks like right now.

```
  state = {
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    title: null,
    blanks: [noun, adjective, verb, etc],
    value: [],
    filledBlanks: []
  };

  handleEnterWord = (e, index) => {
    const word = e.target.value
    const newBlanks = [...this.state.blanks]
    newBlanks[index] = word
    this.setState({blanks: newBlanks})
    console.log(word, newBlanks)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick = {this.handleNewMadlib}>New MadLib</button>
        <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
        {this.state.blanks.map((blank, key) => {
          return <input key={key} placeholder={blank} onChange={()=>this.handleEnterWord(e, key)}/>
        })}
```

**EDIT: I have added some values to the blanks array because I thought the question was a little ambiguous--this will be filled in by an API call in the actual app**

Any help/advice at all is welcome.
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is in

```
 onChange={()=>this.handleEnterWord(e, key)}
```

You should pass the event to the function like this

```
 onChange={(e)=>this.handleEnterWord(e, key)}
```